# C# not running in Unity? (Basic)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm playing around with some C# code in Unity for the first time. I'm creating a little script just to dink around with, not for actual use. This is the error I get:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {

    public int speed = 10;
    public int money = 10;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.back * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return && money >= 10)) {
            Debug.Log("You bought a sword!");
            money - 10;
        } else {
            Debug.Log("You don't have enough money!");
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is in the title. It won't even let me run it. Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks for any help : )

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want to do

```
money -= 10;
```

not

```
money - 10;
```

The first is a decrement so it is allowed where as the second is just an expression (represents a value).